# Map reduce call ambiguous

Tags: swift, reduce

I have the following code:

```
func update(withSlices newSlices: [HAPieChartSlice], totalValue: CGFloat? = nil, animation: HAPieChartAnimation = .none, animationDuration: TimeInterval = 0.0) {
    let totalValue: CGFloat = totalValue ?? newSlices.map({ $0.value }).reduce(0.0, { $0 }) //Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

I'm getting a compilation error on the `reduce` function in the code above. The error is

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I'm not sure why this code is ambiguous since `$0.value` and `totalValue` are both `CGFloat`.

Other relevant code:

```
public struct HAPieChartSlice {
    public let value: CGFloat
    public let color: UIColor
}
```

Why is this call considered ambiguous and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that I wasn't using `reduce` function properly.

The `reduce` method is defined as:

```
func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Element) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

And I was not property combining the result and element parameters in the `nextPartialResult` argument. Since the `initialResult` is `0.0` and I was only reducing using the `result` part (`$0`), Xcode was not able to infer what type I was trying to reduce to.

Changing the code to this fixed the issue:

```
let totalValue: CGFloat = totalValue ?? newSlices.map({ $0.value }).reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 })
```

Since `$1` is a `CGFloat`, Xcode could infer that the result would also be a `CGFloat`.

Comment: `.reduce(0,  +)` Btw Swift is a type inferred language, generally you don't need to explicitly set the type `let totalValue = totalValue ?? newSlices.map{$0.value}.reduce(0,+)`

Comment: Also, you might want to avoid an extra pass over `newSlices` and directly compute the sum of the values with `reduce`, `let totalValue = totalValue ?? newSlices.reduce(0.0) { $0 + $1.value }`.

Comment: thank you both for your feedback. Both are better suggestions than the current implementation.